# MySQL Subquery to get username in different table from user id in current query. How?

Tags: mysql

The following query is the most complex I have been able to learn so far. It calculates SIGN-IN durations from tbl_user_time_log.

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       UTL_DTSTAMP,
       UTL_TASK,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS UTL_DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_TASK,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465615'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/

       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2019-02-24' AND '2019-03-04' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

  /* Our derived table... */
) AS tbl_derived_1

GROUP BY USER_ID, UTL_TASK;
```

...which returns:

[image: query1]

How do I use the same query but for **each user id it selects**, display the **corresponding user first name and user last name** from **tbl_user**?

**tbl_user**

[image: tbl_user]

Comment: Why not another JOIN?

Comment: Sounds like one more join. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Lack of knowledge regarding joins. Took me a second to put this together. There is no problem. I wish to learn how to do this prior to getting downvoted by the impatient AI moderator this site probably has.

Comment: i have the feeling this query will not generate the correct results for the outer SQL. That is not how you should use GROUP BY also i think [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) can't be used to get the correct data from a derived table.. Validate the query with `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')` iám pretty sure you query errors in that mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a table user that contain firstname and lastname related  by id to tbl_user_time_log
you could use a join

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       u.firstname, 
       u.lastname,
       UTL_DTSTAMP,
       UTL_TASK,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS UTL_DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_TASK,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465615'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/

       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2019-02-24' AND '2019-03-04' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

  /* Our derived table... */
) AS tbl_derived_1
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = tbl_derived_1.USER_ID

GROUP BY USER_ID, UTL_TASK;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: no i said derived.. and i said it's documented it can work on a view that the derived table was not menitioned in the documentation.. But that is offcource functional dependence is not the case here because you JOIN back with the table user..  I readed the query wrong because off the missing indent formatting

Comment: @RaymondNijland   . if you pass coffee from Italy I'll offer it to you ..

Comment: Thanks but iam more into the Senseo coffee or Douwe Egberts coffee i think

Comment: A view would be awesome if it didn't make shared hosting go from $20/month to approx $2,000.00/month... funny how you get 20 mysql databases but not ability to create views or stored procedures until you switch to dedicated or more.